# dialog context - how to save?

Tags: c++, winapi, dialog

I'm wondering how to provide context for dialog procedures?

Up to now, I declare static or global variables to provide whatever context I need knowing that the dialog procedure can only be active one time.  However, I find this pretty ugly and wonder if I can pass the context to the dialog procedure through the DialogBoxParam/WM_INITDIALOG/LPARAM mechanism saving it in the INITDIALOG handler using SetWindowLog/GWL_USERDATA?

A few experiments show this might work but I notice that the dialog procedure gets at least one message (namely 30h) before it gets the INITDIALOG message.

So. I'm left with a dilemma.  One of the following occurs to me...

- return FALSE to any message received while GetWindowLong/GWL_USERDATA
  is zero. But do I know its initial value will be zero?
- return FALSE to message 30h.  But are there any other message sent b4
  WM_INITDIALOG?
- Start in a procedure which returns FALSE until it gets a WM_INITDIALOG, then change the dialog procedure using SetWindowLong/GWL_WNDPROC.

I'm also concerned about what other system calls or other uSoft software (stuff I find in the MSDN) might do with GWL_USERDATA.

Comment: Unclear on what exactly you need? You want to save some state of dialog/UI or internal state?

Comment: @Ajay: My goals are doing away with any static or global variables and passing state information to the dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are actually quite a few ways to store context for your window procedures, and dialogs are simply a special case of windows, so these techniques apply.

One way, as you mentioned, is to use `GWLP_USERDATA`/[`GetWindowLongPtr()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633585.aspx)/[`SetWindowLongPtr()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644898.aspx) to store a pointer to the dialog context. Note that the functions are prefixed with `Ptr()`. These functions will work with 32-bit and 64-bit code. The "non-`Ptr()`" functions only work with 32-bit code, so they should not be used.

According to the documentation for `GetWindowLongPtr()`, the `GWLP_USERDATA` value is initially set to zero. So you can always rely on checking if `GetWindowLongPtr()` returns zero and returning `FALSE` from the dialog procedure in those situations.

A dialog procedure using these functions might look something like this:

```
// MyDialogProc is a static function in MyDialogClass. Can also be a global function.
INT_PTR CALLBACK MyDialogClass::MyDialogProc(HWND hwndDlg, UINT uMsg,
    WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    MyDialogClass* target = 0;
    if(uMsg == WM_INITDIALOG)
    {
        target = reinterpret_cast<MyDialogClass*>(lParam);
        ::SetWindowLongPtr(hwndDlg, GWLP_USERDATA,
            reinterpret_cast<LONG_PTR>(target));
    }
    target = reinterpret_cast<MyDialogClass*>(
        ::GetWindowLongPtr(hwndDlg, GWLP_USERDATA));
    if(target != 0)
    {
        // Something like this
        return target->ProcessMessage(hwndDlg, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

And your dialog creation code passes the pointer to an instance of `MyDialogClass` using a member function, possibly like this:

```
void MyDialogClass::Create()
{
    // ....
    // Use CreateDialogParam() or friends to create a dialog and pass
    // the context pointer.
    HWND h = ::CreateDialogParam(hInstance, lpTemplateName, hWndParent,
        &MyDialogClass::MyDialogProc, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(this));
    // ....
}
```

If you prefer a different method (because you're worried that someone else will write over `GWLP_USERDATA`), you can use [GetProp()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633564.aspx)/[SetProp()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633568.aspx)/[RemoveProp()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633567.aspx) and come up with a unique name to identify the pointer. `GetProp()` returns zero if it can't find the property, so again you can rely on checking if it returns zero. This is the method that I use in my library/framework.

A dialog procedure that uses the property functions may look something like this:

```
const wchar_t* myDialogClassContextPtrName = L"MyDlgClsCxtPtr"; // Unicode
// const char* myDialogClassContextPtrName = "MyDlgClsCxtPtr";  // ANSI

// MyDialogProc is a static function in MyDialogClass. Can also be a global function.
INT_PTR CALLBACK MyDialogClass::MyDialogProc(HWND hwndDlg, UINT uMsg,
    WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    MyDialogClass* target = 0;
    if(uMsg == WM_INITDIALOG)
    {
        target = reinterpret_cast<MyDialogClass*>(lParam);
        ::SetProp(hwndDlg, myDialogClassContextPtrName,
            reinterpret_cast<HANDLE>(target));
    }
    target = reinterpret_cast<MyDialogClass*>(
        ::GetProp(hwndDlg, myDialogClassContextPtrName));
    if(target != 0)
    {
        // Something like this
        INT_PTR returnValue = target->ProcessMessage(hwndDlg, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
        if(uMsg == WM_NCDESTROY)
        {
            ::RemoveProp(hwndDlg, myDialogClassContextPtrName);
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

As you have experienced, there are messages that are sent before the `WM_INITDIALOG` message (or the `WM_NCCREATE` message for non-dialog windows). In my experience these messages are inconsequential and will not affect the functionality of your procedure in any way. You can return `FALSE` for the messages that you receive before `WM_INITDIALOG`.

Comment: So ProcessMessage is a __thiscall function in MyClass and has access to all functions and public and  private variables in MyClassDialog?

Comment: @Mike D: Member functions have the `__thiscall` convention by default. It won't matter since the dialog procedure itself has the `CALLBACK` convention. And since it's a member function, it'll have access to all public and private members of `MyClassDialog`.

Comment: @silico: Ok, I think I have it.  Each dialog get it's own class.  I wonder if there's anyway to extend this so several dialogs can have access to the context variables without putting them all in the same class other than by putting some pointer in the context to some other class.  This may seem weird but I have a set of dialogs making up a property sheet.

Comment: @Mike D: You can make `MyDialogClass` a base class for all your dialog classes, make `ProcessMessage()` a virtual function and override it in derived classes. That way, `ProcessMessage()` doesn't have to care what's the actual dialog type is, and you'll be able to process messages and still have access to the member variables (since you wrote the class).